# У меня возникли проблемы с функцией int() из-за того что строка не может стать полностью числом

Tags: python

Вот мой код

```
documents = [
        {"type": "passport", "number": "2207 876234", "name": "Василий Гупкин"},
        {"type": "invoice", "number": "11-2", "name": "Геннадий Покемонов"},
        {"type": "insurance", "number": "10006", "name": "Аристарх Павлов"}
      ]

for copy in documents:
    numbers_0 = copy["number"]

    def doc(copy_of_the_document):
        
        numbers_1 = int(input("Ведите номер нужного вам документа: ").split())
        names = copy_of_the_document["name"]
        if numbers_0 == numbers_1:
          print(names)
        else:
          print("Такого номера не существует")
        return

print(doc(documents))
```

Ошибка которая мне выдается

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(doc(documents))
  File "main.py", line 22, in doc
    numbers_1 = int(input("Ведите номер нужного вам документа: ").split())
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

И я понимаю что тут проблема в int() из-за того что 11-2 в словаре не может стать полностью число, Но я не понимаю как исправить эту ошибку, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: ```input("Ведите номер нужного вам документа: ").split()``` - это список(тр. массив \ набор), а не число \ строка, и именно на то что там список(а не строка) вам компилятор и ругается в данный момент

Comment: + у вас непонятно зачем объявление функции в цикле. `names = copy_of_the_document["name"]` работать не будет: индекс списка не может быть строкой "name". Дальше не досмотрел

Comment: @splash58 Спасибо что указали на ошибку

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Спасибо, теперь разобрался